# How to embed images in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I currently have a list of Products in a SQL database, and one of the fields is a blob field that contains an image of the Product, I store it and retreive it using a Byte[] array, and the image is taken from PNG format.  Displaying the images on the website when a user views a Product is working correctly.

What the customer now wants though is an export of all the products to Excel, including the images to be displayed in each row for each product, lets say Column F.

I've not been finding any information online that seems to work - sample code always seems to have an error or reference things that I can't find, which makes me wonder if there's versioning issues.  I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 and Office 2010 to test this.

I've seen some samples showing how to take the image to Clipboard and paste it, but considering that this will be running on a web server and might have to handle 20 or so products at a time, I'm not sure clipboard would be a good idea for a webserver?

I'd prefer to be able to write it into the excel file directly from the Byte[] array as I'm pulling all the other product data.

Before I update the code on the website, I'm trying to test it locally using a simple Console program.  Once I know I can get an image into Excel, I'll probably write a dll library I can reference on the aspx page.

```
        var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];

        byte[] imgdata = File.ReadAllBytes("product.png");

        //what do I enter here to insert the image into cell[1,1]

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("abc.xlsx");
        xlWorkBook.Close(true);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use worksheet paste function instead of using `AddPicture` if you want to use byte data instead of files on hard disk:

```
Bitmap bmp;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imgdata))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp, False);
    var rng = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1");
    xlWorkSheet.Paste(rng, bmp);
}
```

Comment: Would using clipboard be advisable running on a web page?

Comment: I get the error "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it." - this is similar to another thread I saw the suggestion for clipboard where the guy was saying he was struggling to get it working on an aspx page.

Comment: If you use OLE calls like `Clipboard` you must add `[STAThread]` above the method. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2411f889-8e30-4a6d-9e28-8a46e66c0fdb/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-mode-before-ole?forum=clr

Comment: Is there any way to resize and change the position of the image? I used the above code. It helped but I cannot change the width and height of the image... Any help would be appreciated. Thank you,